# Not able to play audio link with html in WebView

Tags: android, webview

I have loaded html code in WebView. In that html code we are getting some audio files. When user click on the speaker button we want to play that audio files. We are not able to play that audio files.

Below is my code :

```
 val s1 = URLEncoder.encode(htmlString!!, "UTF-8")
                val s = URLDecoder.decode(s1, "UTF-8")
                wbContent.loadData(s, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in intercepting the link as such:

```
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.endsWith(".mp3")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "audio/*");
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);   
        return true;
    } else if (url.endsWith(".mp4") || url.endsWith(".3gp")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "video/*");
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);   
            return true;
    } else {
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }
 }
```